# undefined method `name' for [1, 2]:Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models `Year` and `Subject` , I am trying to show the list of subjects name of each particular Year , but when I open the show action I'm getting this error . I don't know why it is returning an array of Ids instead of objects .

show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>   <strong>Name:</strong>   <%= @year.name %> </p>

<p>   <strong>list of subjects:</strong>

    <ul>
      <li><%= @year.subject_ids.name %></li>
    </ul>    </p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_year_path(@year) %> | <%= link_to 'Back', years_path %>
```

Year.rb

```
class Year < ApplicationRecord
  has_many  :subjects

end
```

Subject.rb

```
class Subject < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to  :year
end
```

Years_controller.rb

```
class YearsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_year, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /years
  # GET /years.json
  def index
    @years = Year.all
  end

  # GET /years/1
  # GET /years/1.json
  def show

  end

  # GET /years/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /years
  # POST /years.json
  def create
    @year = Year.new(year_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @year.save
        format.html { redirect_to @year, notice: 'Year was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @year }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @year.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /years/1
  # PATCH/PUT /years/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @year.update(year_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @year, notice: 'Year was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @year }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @year.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /years/1
  # DELETE /years/1.json
  def destroy
    @year.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to years_url, notice: 'Year was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_year
      @year = Year.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def year_params
      params.require(:year).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

Comment: post the code for action from controller

Comment: Just edited the question @DeepakMahakale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this line:

```
@year.subject_ids.name
```

It looks like you have one-to-many relationship between `Year` and `Subject` models.

`@year.subject_ids` returns you an array of subject `id`s that belong to that `@year`. That's the error you have.

Which of those subject's name do you want to show?! That's your logical error.

If you want to show a list of all subject names in a list then update your code to this:

```
<ul>
  <% @year.subjects.each do |subject| %>
    <li><%= subject.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you @Uzbekjon , that was it .

Answer (score 0):

Try following code in show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p><strong>Name:</strong> <%= @year.name %></p>

<p><strong>list of subjects:</strong>    
    <ul>
      <li><%= @year.subjects.map(&:name) %></li>
    </ul>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_year_path(@year) %> | <%= link_to 'Back', years_path %>
```